# Nested object null on client side in CODE FIRST EF RIA Service

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, wcf-ria-services

I have nested object in EF Code First using Silverlight RIA service, I am able to get the data at service side but when I see it on client side child objects are null. Could you please guide me what's wrong.

```
[HasSelfValidation]
public class Batch
{

    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public string BatchName { get; set; }
    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [Association("FK_Batch_BathSetItemSet", "BatchId", "BatchSetIdItemSetId")]
    public virtual ICollection<BatchSetItemSet> BatchSetItemSets { get; set; }
 }
public class BatchSetItemSet
{

    public int BatchSetIdItemSetId { get; set; }
    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ItemSetId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public  Batch Batch { get; set; }
     [Include]
     [Composition]
     [Association("FK_BathSetItemSet_ItemSet", "BatchSetIdItemSetId", "ItemSetId")]
    public  ItemSet ItemSet { get; set; }
}
public class ItemSet
{

    public int ItemSetId { get; set; }
    public int CustodianId { get; set; }
    public string ItemSetName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BatchSetItemSet> BatchSetItemSets { get; set; }
    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [Association("FK_ItemSet_Custodian", "ItemSetId", "CustodianId")]
    public virtual Custodian Custodian { get; set; }
}
```

and service call is :    `this.DbContext.Batches.Include("BatchSetItemSets.ItemSet.Custodian").Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: How are you trying to load your entities client side ? Please, post the code

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question properly, I have WCF RIA service which I am calling using following call: this.DbContext.Batches.Include("BatchSetItemSets.ItemSet.Custodian").Where(x => x.BatchId == batchId).SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

You are close with the attributes, but they need to be changed:

```
[HasSelfValidation]
public class Batch
{
    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public string BatchName { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [Association("FK_Batch_BathSetItemSet", "BatchId", "BatchId", IsForeignKey = false)]
    public virtual ICollection<BatchSetItemSet> BatchSetItemSets { get; set; }
 }

public class BatchSetItemSet
{
    public int BatchSetIdItemSetId { get; set; }
    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ItemSetId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Association("FK_Batch_BathSetItemSet", "BatchId", "BatchId")]
    public Batch Batch { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Association("FK_BathSetItemSet_ItemSet", "ItemSetId", "ItemSetId")]
    public ItemSet ItemSet { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSet
{
    public int ItemSetId { get; set; }
    public int CustodianId { get; set; }
    public string ItemSetName { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [Association("FK_BathSetItemSet_ItemSet", "ItemSetId", "ItemSetId", IsForeignKey = false)]
    public virtual ICollection<BatchSetItemSet> BatchSetItemSets { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Association("FK_ItemSet_Custodian", "CustodianId", "CustodianId")]
    public virtual Custodian Custodian { get; set; }
}
```

The `AssociationAttribute` .ctor is defined as:

```
AssociationAttribute(string name, string thisKey, string otherKey)
```

It should be configured as:

- `name`: A unique name shared by each end of the relationship
- `thisKey`: The name of the Property on this object that represents the key or foreign key
- `otherKey`: The name of the Property on the other object that represents the key or foreign key
- `IsForeignKey`: A property on `AssociationAttribute` to indicate if this end of the relationship is the primary key or the foreign key. It defaults to `true` (meaning this navigation property is a Foreign Key). By setting it to `false`, you indicate to WCF RIA that this object contains the Primary Key. For all `AssociationAttribute` usages with a given `name`, only one is allowed to have `IsForeignKey = false`. Otherwise, you will get a build error.

Comment: Thanks @Chapel, unfortunately we thought it is something to do with CodeFirst approach & due to some other concerns we thought of moving to EDMX approach & got it fixed. But thanks much for getting it clarified. I will surely try this in POC & getback to you if any issues happen. Thanks once again for your time